# Return std::array of unknown size

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array

I would like to return a multidimensional std::array from my function. The size of the returned array shall be determined by the size of an input argument.
Something like:

```
std::array<std::array<unsigned int, n>, n> foo(std::vector<int> vec){
    unsigned int n = vec.size;
    std::array<std::array<unsigned int, n>, n> result;
    return result;
}
```

It would be nice to solve this without an annoying additional template argument. std::vector instead of std::array seems not to be as straightforward to initialize with n (undetermined) items as std::array (without explicit initialization). How can this be made possible? Thank you!

Comment: The size of an `std::array` must be known at compile time. That's why the size is templated

Comment: Why do you need to use std::array as a return type rather than std::vector?

Comment: @ F. Salido: For C-style like arrays, you can do someting like:

    int[] foo() { // ...

@N. Butterworth: If I used std::vector, I would have to initialize the complete object with n^2 elements with a nested for-loop -- I strive to omit this.
@George; If there is no better solution than your best-so-far one, I would like to see them as an answer to be able to mark it as the best one :-)

Comment: @user7427029 `int[] foo()` doesn't compile, as well as `int foo()[]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that's an extension I believe.. only way to organize and return  multidimensional array of size that wasn't known at compile time is a naked pointer, or a class that is a wrapper  class around naked pointer. vectors are ok to act as replacement, a redefined iterator ma allow a trick of emulating multidimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you need to know is that `std::array` has its size fixed at compile time, as the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) from cppreference sais:

> std::array is a container that encapsulates fixed size arrays.
>
> This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a
>   struct holding a C-style array T[N] as its only non-static data
>   member.

If `n` comes from `std::cin` or from the command line arguments (or whatever kind of input out of compile time), then the compiler can't deduce the type, and therefore it will throw an error.

The most sensible way to do this is with `std::vector`, and you can do it like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> foo(std::vector<int> vec){
    unsigned int n = vec.size();
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> result(n, std::vector<unsigned int>(n));
    return result;
}
```

Just initialize every vector using the size constructor of the vector.

Comment: I looks like that RVO in this case is impossible

Comment: @Swift Well, you can always force a move if you don't want to create a new copy, it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `n` sized `std::vector` of `n` sized `std::vector` s using its c'tor, i.e:

`std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> result(n, std::vector<unsigned int>(n, 0));`

NOTE: According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), the second parameter used in  the above example of `std::vector` s c'tor is for the value of each item to be created: c'tor signature:

`vector( size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());`.

Comment: it's possible, but it is allocation cost nightmare..  or nightmare for anyone who would try to multithread, using such structure of storage

Comment: @Swift "it's possible, but it is allocation cost nightmare" Why? And I doubt multithreading is relevant but why would it be an issue to use `std::vector<std::vector<>>`(especially in a small program)?

Comment: C++ is a language that can hides complexity of code behind simple structures  That type is essentially an array with uneven lines, because every "line"  represented by vector and can change its size independently. But it's not an analog of python's numty. There is no way to represent it as 2D array without copying all data to another storage. If OP _ever_ needs to do the latter (very common problem with working with numerous APIs (e.g. OpenGL) or interfacing with python or other languages), only effective way  he can do it  is to make a wrapper class  around single  dimensional vector.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html). It allows you to create multidimensional arrays with contents of arbitrary content type. I have used it (the boost::multi_array_ref part to be more specific) and it works pretty nice. An important feature is the ability to create array [views](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_views) (and slices based on views).